# HIghchart 3d piechart pointer is not pointing correct color

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I have implemented the piechart using highcart. Highchart 3d piechart pointer is not pointing correct color. It is pointing the wrong area. But If I removed 3d options it is working as expected. Please find the below code snippet and screenshot.

```
chart: {
    renderTo: element[0],
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    type: "pie",
    options3d: {
        enabled: true,
        alpha: 45,
        beta: 0
    },
    height: dynamicHieght,
    verticalAlign: 'top'
},
title: {
    text: ''
},
credits: {
    enabled: false
},
exporting: false,

legend: {
    enabled: false
},
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{point.name} - {point.incomingTaffic}</b>',
    headerFormat: ''
},
plotOptions: {
    pie: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        depth: 35,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '{point.y}%'
        }
    }
},
series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    name: "Traffic in bps",
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: scope.chartconfig.data,
    colors: ["#5DA5DA", "#F17CB0", "#414a89", "#ff8b80", "#ffa661", "#74beec" , "#ffbf00", "#b67bd1",  "#ffc54c",  "#e4e34f",  "#b2ff73",  "#60d394",  "#ee6055"]
}]
```

[image]

Comment: That looks quite strange. Could you try to provide me with some live working example? Unfortunately I cannot reproduce the issue basing on attached code. In this example, everything looks as it should: https://jsfiddle.net/wb84h0fc/

Comment: Hi, I'm not able to share you due to some security reason. I have edited your example with high chart 5.0.14 version. But Here it is working. Still I'm not able to find the solution.
https://jsfiddle.net/wb84h0fc/3/

Comment: Finally I foound the root cause for the issue. I just removed **highcharts-3d.src.js**  file from my index.html